# Как работать с for в twig?

Tags: php, циклы, twig

Искал в google,но так и не разобрался как в twig написать :

```
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
      echo 'hi';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

прежде всего искать надо [в официальной документации:](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

```
{% for i in 0..3 %}
    hi
{% endfor %}
```